# Can forming an LLC be beneficial when earning foreign income?

Tags: united-states, taxes, limited-liability-company, international, consulting

I'm a full-time salaried employee in the US.  I have the opportunity to do some freelance foreign work on the side while continuing to live in the US.

Would it be beneficial to register an LLC and conduct this foreign work/receive payments through that?  Or can I use the [Foreign Earned Income Exclusion](http://www.irs.gov/Individuals/International-Taxpayers/Foreign-Earned-Income-Exclusion) to my advantage?

Comment: what kind of work will you be doing?

Answer (score 2):

LLC is a liability protection tool and foreign earned income exclusion is a tax topic. They're orthogonal.

Regarding LLC you should talk to a liability attorney, since the main goal of the LLC is separation of assets and limiting your liability exposure.

Foreign earned income exclusion is irrelevant for you, since you said you'll be living in the US, thus your income will not be foreign-sourced.